# filter array of objects by methods of another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I am making a food delivery app and I have two different array of objects. One of them is `cartItems` and the other is `foodItems`. The arrays can be of different sizes. So what do I want to loop over each array and check

1. if the ids of both the array match.
2. `Note` I want to check if the quantity exists then increment it by the new quantity else simply add a new quantity
3. check if itemDetails exists in `foodItems` array and if it exists, check if the `price` of cartItems matches of that foodItem, then update the `cartItems` object, else remove them.
4. if itemDetails does not exist then update the quantity of the item.

**Update**
**If there are two items with similar id and price, the quantities should be added**

Here is my **cartItems**:

```
let cartItems = [
  { id: 1, price: 120, quantity: 7 },
  { id: 2, price: 70, quantity: 4 },
  { id: 1, price: 70, quantity: 3 },
  { id: 3, price: 60, quantity: 1 },
  {id: 1, price: 120, quantity: 2}
];
```

Here is my **foodItems**

```
let foodItems = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: "chicken",
    itemDetails: [
   { 
    price: 120, 
    details: "2 pcs of chicken biryani"
   }, 
    {
     price: 70, 
     details: "1 pcs of chicken biryani"
     }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mutton",
    itemDetails: [
      {
        price: 120,
        details: "Two pieces of mutton biryani",
      },
     {
      price: 70,
      details: "one pcs of mutton biryani" 
     },
    ],
  },
  

  { id: 3, name: "Ice Cream", price: 60 },
];
```

This is my desired output

```
let filteredArrayOuput = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Chicken Biryani",
    itemDetails: [
      {
        price: 120,
        details: "Two pieces of chicken Biryani",
      },
    ],
    quantity: 7,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mutton Biryani",
    itemDetails: [
      {
        price: 70,
        details: "Two pieces of mutton biryani",
      },
    ],
    quantity: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    price: "Chicken Biryani",
    quantity: 3,
    itemDetails: [
      {
        price: 70,
        details: "Two pieces of Chicken Biryani",
      },
    ],
  },
  { id: 3, price: 60, quantity: 1 },
];
```

This is what I have done till now

```
const filterFunc = (arr, price) => {
  let filtered = arr.filter((item) => {
    return item.price == price;
  });
  return filtered;
};

const filterArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const filtered = arr2.filter((el) => {
    let arr = arr1.find(({ id, quantity, price }) => {
      if (el.id === id) {
         if (el.itemDetails !== undefined && el.itemDetails.length !== 0) {
           let itemDetails = el.itemDetails;
           return (
             (el.quantity = quantity),
             (el.itemDetails = filterFunc(itemDetails, price))
           );
         } else {
           return (el.quantity = quantity);
         }
      }
    });

    return arr;
  });
  return filtered;
};
console.log(filterArray(cartItems, foodItems))
```

Comment: `if (el.id === id) {
        console.log(id, price);
        return id;` If you are returning id, then you are never going to next code blocks.

Comment: Sorry, I have removed the return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the below code.

1. Find `existingFoodItem` from FoodItems array
2. Find `priceObj` by comparing price
3. return new object with price details if itemDetails exists (checking with `?`), else without price if no itemDetails exists.

```js
let cartItems = [
      { id: 1, price: 120, quantity: 7 },
      { id: 1, price: 120, quantity: 1 },
      { id: 2, price: 70, quantity: 4 },
      { id: 1, price: 70, quantity: 3 },
      { id: 3, price: 60, quantity: 1 },
    ];

    let foodItems = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "chicken",
        itemDetails: [
       { 
        price: 120, 
        details: "2 pcs of chicken biryani"
       }, 
        {
         price: 70, 
         details: "1 pcs of chicken biryani"
         }
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Mutton",
        itemDetails: [
          {
            price: 120,
            details: "Two pieces of mutton biryani",
          },
         {
          price: 70,
          details: "one pcs of mutton biryani" 
         },
        ],
      },
      

      { id: 3, name: "Ice Cream", price: 60 },
    ];


    let result = [];
    
    cartItems.forEach(cart => {
      let esitingItem = result.find(r => r.id === cart.id && r.itemDetails.find(i => i.price === cart.price));
      if(esitingItem){
       esitingItem.quantity += cart.quantity;
       return;
      }
      let existingFoodItem = foodItems.find(food => food.id === cart.id);
      if(existingFoodItem){
        let priceObj = existingFoodItem.itemDetails?.find(item => item.price === cart.price);
        if(priceObj){
          result.push({id:cart.id,name:existingFoodItem.name,itemDetails:[{...priceObj}],quantity:cart.quantity});
        }
        else{
          return result.push({id:cart.id,name:existingFoodItem.name,quantity:cart.quantity});
        }
      }
    });


    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Bro, there is a problem what if I have another object [{id: 1, price: 120, quantity: 3}] and many more similar types. What I want to achieve is to add the previous quantity to the new one.

Comment: Yours is valid point, I have updated the code

Comment: Welcome mate :)